# Type vs. value constructors in typeclasses

Tags: haskell, typeclass

I am learning Haskell and am confused by [this example](http://learnyouahaskell.com/making-our-own-types-and-typeclasses#kinds-and-some-type-foo).

Consider the following:

```
class Tofu t where
    tofu :: j a -> t a j

data Frank a b = Frank {frankField :: b a} deriving (Show)

instance Tofu Frank where
    tofu x = Frank x
```

Why is it that when making `Frank` an instance of `Tofu`, we provide (as far as I understand), a type constructor `Frank x`, instead of a value constructor, i.e. `tofu x = Frank {frankField = x}`?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You're still using the value constructor. You can use types that have record fields without having to use the record syntax to construct them, so `Frank x` does the same thing as `Frank { frankField = x }`.

If you have more than one record field, e.g.:

```
data Frank a b = Frank { frankA :: a, frankB :: b }
```

... then the fields appear in the order you have written them in, so you can do:

```
-- With x :: a, y :: b
Frank x y
```

Comment: Ah! I suppose I was confused by the fact that both the type and the value constructor(s) were named `Frank`... thank you!

Comment: Yes, that can be a little confusing at first. Just remember that if you see a CapitalizedIdentifier in a type signature/class declaration/etc it's going to be a type name and everywhere else it's going to be a constructor.

Comment: @d125q More specifically, type names don't share the same namespace as value constructor names and function/value names.